# OutputStream and InputStream for inter-thread communication

Tags: java

I have the following problem:

I am given a module with the following API:

```
    public void start(InputStream input, OutputStream output,
        InputStream error, PipeListener<T> listener)
```

The purpose of this module is to facilitate communication between the main system and external processes (in this case, instances of Process).

What I am trying to do is to implement a "mock process", which actually is a Thread instance, but has its own pseudo input, output and error streams. The key thing here is the nature of the streams themselves, for example, I want the stream implementation returned by

```
((MockProcess)mockProcess).getInputStream()
```

to be functionally identical to

```
((Process)realProcess).getInputStream().
```

For all intents and purposes, they should be completely interchangeable.

Which InputStream and OutputStream implementation (respectively) should I use to achieve this? The only suggestion I have been able to find is to use piped streams...but is this really the best option?

Comment: This is a common question for integration testing.  Some searches on that topic may help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say they are the best option because pipes are used for interprocess communications on unix. You should avoid any form of I/O on disks. And you should avoid all heavy tcp/ip overload. So pipes are really the best option.

Comment: He wasn't talking about OS pipes.  He was referring to Java  PipedInputStream, PipedOutputStream

Comment: I know. I was just comparing the same problem across systems: how to let threads communicate in java? how do threads communicate in an OS? Pipes are the best solutions. Java pipes have the same advantage: no I/O on disk, no tcp/ip required, they block after sending too much data.
The way pipes block is probably the most important factor. No other Java Input/Output stream block the same way.